# What is wrong with my file reading function?

Tags: python

this is my python code, I am trying to implement the function to read files. What I am doing wrong?

```
def read_words(words_file):
    """ (file open for reading) -> list of str

    Return a list of all words (with newlines removed) from open file
    words_file.

    Precondition: Each line of the file contains a word in uppercase characters
    from the standard English alphabet.
    """
    words_file = open("words_file", "r")
    for lines in words_file:
        return (lines, end='')
    words_file.close()

read_words("file:///C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/a3_wordlist1.txt")
```

Comment: did you try `for lines in words_file.read():`

Comment: Using `return` will return the data and quit the function, what you want is to create an empty list, append each line to it, and when the for loop is over, just after closing the file, you return that list.

Comment: Also, your parameter with the name of the file to open is called `words_file`. And thats what you need to use in open, (`"words_file"` > `words_file`)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this...

```
f = open('filename', 'r')
words = []
for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.strip('\n')
    words.extend(line.split(' '))
f.close()
```